# Why does TotalCount property on public folder always return 0 items?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange 2013 SP1 and Exchange Web Services managed API 2.2 to try and get a list of the contacts in a contact folder that I have stored in Public Folders.  **I would like to limit the size of the ItemView to the total number of contacts that I have in this contact folder**, but when I try to return that property (contactfolder.TotalCount) it always returns 0.  If I try this with using the Contact folder under my mailbox a value other than 0 is returned.  I can get around this issue by either specifying a value for the constructor for the ItemView as either a specific number or by using int.MaxValue, but I would rather use the total number of items that are in the contact list.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!  Here is the relevant code:

```
private FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item> ExchangeContacts()
    {
        // Setup the exchange server connection.
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("someone@mydomain.com");

        // Set the filter to choose the correct contact list
        SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "My Public Contacts");
        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection filterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection();
        filterCollection.Add(filter);           


        // Get the FolderId using the search filter.
        Folder parent = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
        FindFoldersResults results = parent.FindFolders(filter, new FolderView(1));
        FolderId fid = results.Single().Id;

        // Get the Contact folder based on the folderid.
        ContactsFolder contactsfolder = (ContactsFolder)results.Single();            
        ItemView view = new ItemView(contactsfolder.TotalCount);

        // Set the property that need to be shown in the page.
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DisplayName, ContactSchema.CompanyName, ContactSchema.LastModifiedTime, ContactSchema.BusinessAddressCity, ContactSchema.BusinessAddressPostalCode, ContactSchema.BusinessAddressState, ContactSchema.BusinessAddressStreet, ContactSchema.HomeAddressCity, ContactSchema.HomeAddressPostalCode, ContactSchema.HomeAddressState, ContactSchema.HomeAddressStreet, ContactSchema.ItemClass, ContactSchema.FileAs, ContactSchema.LastModifiedName);
        //view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DisplayName);

        // Order the results by one of the selected properties
        //view.OrderBy.Add(ContactSchema.LastModifiedTime, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SortDirection.Descending);           

        FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item> contactItems = contactsfolder.FindItems(view);

        return contactItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recreated your public folder (immediately under the public folder root), added a contact to it, and ran your code and get a contactItems.TotalCount value of 1 (as expected). However, after discussing this with the Exchange product team I learned that FindFolder can return an incorrect value if the FindFolder request gets routed to the public folder mailbox that doesn't have the content of the public folder. So TotalCount can return an incorrect value and is not supported for public folders. We will get the documentation updated to reflect this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[FindFolder operation (Exchange 2013)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563918%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx):

> Using the Default value for the BaseShape, the response returns the
> folder name, the folder ID, the number of subfolders, the number of
> child folders found in the folder, and the count of unread items.
>
> <...>
>
> FindFolder responses to a request with the AllProperties response
> shape will not return the TotalCount and UnreadCount elements for
> public folder searches.

Guess you need to specify a property filter in the search criteria.